Lucee Not Reading htaccess File
I recently installed Lucee on Windows using the installer "lucee-5.4.5.23-windows-x64-installer" and am testing a website that previously ran using Coldfusion.
Everything works well, except that the htaccess file isn't being read, which handles the Search Engine Safe (SES) Urls. Previously the URL mywebsite.com/profiles would translate to mywebsite.com/index.cfm?do=profiles using the htaccess rule:
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.cfm?do=$1 [NC,L] 
Currently, if I run http://127.0.0.1:8888/mywebsite/profiles, it gives the error
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Message The requested resource [/mywebsite//profiles] is not available

However, if I run the page http://127.0.0.1:8888/mywebsite/index.cfm?do=profiles it does work as expected.
This leads me to believe that the htaccess file isn't being read/seen. I have tested this by adding some garbage to the htaccess file to see if it would cause the website to error, but it does not. So this file appears to be being ignored/bypassed.
Is there anything else I have to do since installing Lucee to get this to work properly? At my Lucee webhost, the htaccess file is detected and works perfectly. So it's just my local machine with this new installation of Lucee that seems to missing something.
Thanks.

The htaccess file is entirely/a specific apache webserver configuration file. Lucee has nothing to do with it. For that file to be read you'll need to use the apache webserver and set its directives to read and use it.

With regards to this URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/mywebsite/profiles
... it does not work because it does not have a "/" at the end. Try this URL instead, and it will work:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/mywebsite/profiles/
This has to do with what are referred to as "handlers" in web server speak. The / at the end will indicate a directory, which will trigger the default document protocol. If you have index.cfm set up as a default document, the handler will see your ".cfm" and know how to handle that request.
Traditionally, SES URL's sometimes require a little extra configuration because the default mechanisms that pass a request back to Tomcat do not exist in SES URL's. Specifically, the Tomcat connectors require a ".cfm" in the URL in order for it to know that the request needs to be passed to Tomcat (and then the Lucee servlet within Tomcat). Since your SES URL does not have a ".cfm", in it's request, or a default document that includes a CFM, the web server does not know how to properly handle the request.
This is likely what's happening with your Apache .htaccess files as well. It's likely an "order of execution" issue where the .htaccess is processed AFTER the CFM handler is processed from the main apache config file. If you included a CFM handler INSIDE your .htaccess files, then Apache would know to pass the request back to Tomcat. You could also just include your .htaccess configuration into your Apache virtualhost and have it processed before the CFM handler to fix this issue.
Almost all issues of this kind have to do with handlers and their order of execution, and sometimes you just have to fiddle with it a little bit to make it work how you want it to.
Hope this helps!
